# OL3: Getting overlayed layers by coordinate

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to get different overlayed layers by clicking on the map so that the user can choose which one want to get feature info through a pop-up.
I am using map.forEachFeatureAtPixel but I just get one of the overlayed layers.

```
var prue=[];
layers=[]
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) { 


    l=layer.get('name');
    console.log("CAPA:",l)
    layers.push(l);
    console.log(layers);




    if (layer == rustic_wfs){
    var capa= "rustica";
    prue[0]=capa;
    return feature;};

    if (layer == zonas_wfs){
    var capa="zonas";
    prue[0]=capa;
    return feature;}


    });

    map.on('click', function(evt) {
    displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ol.Map#forEachFeatureAtPixel` will be called with all features at the provided pixel until you return a truthy value, which you do in your snippet (`return feature`). So to get all features, never return a truthy value. The function needs to look something like this:

```
var layers = [];
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
  if (layers.indexOf(layer) == -1) {
    layers.push(layer);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function displayFeatureInfo(evt) {
    var txt = "";

    olMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, source) {

        //In the feature is the information of layer
        //In the source is the layer

        //you can save the "source" in you array to get all layers 

        var features = feature.getProperties();

        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(features).forEach(function (campo, idx, array) {

            var valor = features[campo];

            txt += "<b>" + campo + ":</b> " + valor + "<br />";         
        });

        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;

        content.innerHTML = "<p style='padding: 0px'><b>Información:</b></p>" + txt + "<br/>";
        txt += "<br/>------------------------<br/><br/>";
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
    });
};
```

Ignore "overlay" and "content", it is the way like I show the pop-up

Comment: I tried to save the sources or layers and then looping them, but I think the problem is still there. When I click two overlayed layers it just recognize one of them. Could it be that the function is not propper for this purpose?

Comment: See your "return feature", when you return into a loop, it break the loop and no continue with the other layers, in other words, you only have a loop of 1 iteraction, I recommend save the feature into your array, something like "var layerinfo = {features: feature, layers: layer}" and then "layers.push(layerinfo)" so you can get all layers and all features after the loop finish